# Как вернуть строку черз маршалинг

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно вернуть строку с кода написанного на С++ в С#.

Код на С++:

```
extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport)
char* GetString()
{
char* someString=new char[10] {"Hello"};
return someString;
}

extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport)
void Test()
{
cout << "Test";
}
```

Код на C#:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
private const string DllPath = @"..\..\..\Debug\VirtualFolder.dll";

    [DllImport(DllPath)]
    public static extern string GetString();

    [DllImport(DllPath)]
    public static extern void Test();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NativeMethods.Test(); // Test на экране
        string name = NativeMethods.GetString(); // ошибка на этапе выполнения
        Console.Write(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: вроде, строки C/C++ и C# это "две большие разницы": (null-terminated C-string) массив однобайтных символов завершающийся `\0`, (C++-string) псевдоним для `std::basic_string<…>` и (C#) класс, хранящий в т.ч. массив двухбайтных символов Unicode, длину строки (кол-во элементов массива) и пр. св-ва.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Для управления подобными ситуациями существует атрибут [MarshalAsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):</s>

```
[DllImport(DllPath)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string GetString();
```

Comment: Да, такой атрибут существует, только вот если вы запустите этот код на примере с С++ кодом в вопросе, он упадет с ошибкой. По-этому я предложил более стабильный код, который не пытается очистить неуправляемую память, занятую строкой.

Answer (score 3):

Придется делать вот так:

```
[DllImport("CppDll.dll", EntryPoint= "GetString")]
private static extern IntPtr _GetString();

public static string GetString() => Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(_GetString());
```